# How to grant billing-only access to an Azure subscription?

Tags: azure

I have a non-technical client, for whom I have set up an Azure subscription with some critical resources, and I would rather he did not login as an Azure subscription admin on a daily basis, because I consider his machines untrusted. Still, I want him to be able to manage his invoices and billing. Would it possible to grant his Microsoft account only enough permission for that? If yes, how?

Comment: Is this a regular account, or an Enterprise Agreement?

Comment: It's a Pay-As-You-Go subscription.

Comment: If your regularly reselling Azure Services you may want to look at Azure CSP

Answer (score 2):

According to your description, we can set **Billing Reader** to add permissions to Azure account, in this way, we can use this account to view Invoices and others.

Here are the steps to set permission to Azure account:
1.Login Azure new portal with global admin account.
2.Select `Subscriptions`, then select `Access control`, `add permissions` like this:
[image]
3.After this we can use this account to login Azure portal to view **subscriptions**' Invoices.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.